# how to fix ErrorException Undefined property App\Controllers\User::$form_validation CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

> I got an error trying to function edit
>
> [image]
>
> to be honest I'm confused about placing the form validation library in
> codeigniter 4. can you guys help me?

user.php

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Controllers;
    
    class User extends BaseController
    {
    
        protected $db, $builder;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
         
            $this->db     = \Config\Database::connect();
            $this->builder = $this->db->table('users');
       }
    
        public function index()
        {
            $data['title'] = 'My Profile';
            return view('user/index', $data);
        }
    
        public function edit()
        {
    
            $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';
            $db     = \Config\Database::connect();
            $query =   $this->builder->get();
            $data['user'] = $query->getRow();
    
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Fullname', 'required|trim');
    
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false); {
                $this->load->view('user/edit', $data);
            }
    
            return view('user/edit', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in CI 4 form validation library is renamed  https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for validation

```
$test = $this->validate(['name' => 'required|trim']);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nominxx, you use the `setRules()` method instead of `setRule()`. setRules() method accept the array.

[Read the official CI4 Docs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#:%7E:text=This%20method%20sets%20a%20single,array%20that%20is%20sent%20in.)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Fullname', 'required|trim');
```

Change it to

```
$this->form_validation->setRule('name', 'Fullname', 'required|trim');
```

Comment: I have changed it but the error that appears is still the same

Comment: Read the doc, it definitely useful. It's so simple to use.

Comment: Should I add form validation to autoload?